# Anime film in which a young boy is riding a Pegasus that turns into a weapon

Tags: story-identification, anime

I’m trying to find an anime film I had on VHS when I was younger. It would have been in the 90s or maybe the late 80s.

I can only remember one scene in which a young boy is riding a Pegasus and he shouts "Pegasus energise Pegasus fire" and it turns into  a weapon and blows snoring that was attacking a spacecraft/aircraft and the boy runs out to be a robot when he is found on the ground.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I'm confused as to what you meant by "blows snoring" though. Also, when you said "runs out to be a robot," did you mean " **turns** out to be a robot?"

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and that should be blows something up

Answer (score 3):

Based off [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/104h1v5/comment/j34zol9/), I think this might be Dino Mech Gaiking:

> **Q**: So in the early-mid 90s I remember having a VHS of what I recall to be a badly dubbed anime […]
>
> Essentially there is an android/cyborg boy with yellow/orange hair and wearing a white "dress" like outfit, maybe similar to a toga or something. Hewas accompanied by a Pegasus which may have also been a robot of some kind. Both the boy and pegasus look "real" though and I sont think the main characters realised he/they are androids until the boy gets hurt in some way.
>
> […] I remember when thr boy wanted to attack he would shout "PEGASUS FIRE" and I think the horse shot some flames out his mouth or nose
>
> **A**: That's [episode 26](https://trakt.tv/shows/dino-mech-gaiking/seasons/1/episodes/26) of [Dino Mech Gaiking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaiking). This is one of the '70s anime series that was dubbed and syndicated in the US as the anthology show Force Five. (Gaiking was the Friday show.) [Here's the intro](https://youtu.be/DrmTNkeDUvg).
>
> You were probably watching the same VHS that my local video store had where they edited a few of the dubbed Gaiking episodes from Force Five into a feature-length movie. Episode 26 with the Pegasus was the "middle" bit of this movie.